# .htaccess AuthBasic if custom environment variable equals expression

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, environment-variables, typo3

My aim is to require an Authorization whenever the custom environment variable **TYPO3_CONTEXT** is not equal to `'Production'`. Meaning that, i want to force Authorization on non Production contexts.

This is what i've got in my .htaccess:

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/htpasswd
AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthType Basic

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Satisfy any
Require valid-user
Allow from env=(TYPO3_CONTEXT=='Production')

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev.\example.\com$
RewriteRule .? - [E=TYPO3_CONTEXT:Development]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.\example.\com$
RewriteRule .? - [E=TYPO3_CONTEXT:Production]
```

What would be the right Syntax in the line:

```
Allow from env=(TYPO3_CONTEXT=='Production')
```

Is it possible at all to query the env variable at this early stage, cause the rewrite rule is defined afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

You can not match against env directly in an allow directive, You will first need to match against the predefined env  using a SetEnvIfNoCase directive and then  the allow directive :

```
#1)step 1 
SetEnvIfNoCase TYPO3_CONTEXT !production allowed=1
#2)step 2
AuthUserFile /var/www/htpasswd
AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthType Basic

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Satisfy any
Require valid-user
Allow from env=allowed
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_setenvif.html

Comment: thank you. the only problem is, that the the value of the TYPO3_CONTEXT is set through a RewriteCond / RewriteRule